Android: OnNewIntent overrides nothing
After recent updates to several libraries in my gradle, when I built my project, it gives me these two errors:
1. 'OnNewIntent' overrides nothing
2. 'dispatchKeyEvent' overrides nothing

I see that these functions are now locked and cannot be overridden. But what are the alternate to these functions now?

Please share you Activity class declaration

Please provide a full [mre] that we can use to reproduce the problem ourselves.

The parameter just became not Nullable. So just remove ? for the type KeyEvent
Change this
override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent?)

to
override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent)

Same goes for OnNewIntent
